# Security issues while using external javascript and php files to access mysql database in drupal nodes

Tags: security

I have created a search_interface node which asks for filters and `onClick` event of the `submit button`, I have called an external `search.js` script. My search_interface node is of a custom content type `Query`(this content type has no extra fields other than the default fields created by a new content type)

This script uses `getElementById()` to get user input and send it to an external php script using `POST` method. This script uses `mysqli_connect()` to connect to my database and then does query on the required table(only 1 table is being queried everytime). The result of `mysqli_query()` is passed back to the search.js script using `json_encode()` and in the `search.js` script, I have parsed this jsonData and created a `table string`.  Then I have used `my_table.innerHTML = "table string"` to finally display the query on the drupal node.

- Is this method secure?
- Can some anonymous user access my .php script and get to know my
  mysql admin password? ( I use admin password during `mysqli_connect()` )
- Can my whole database be exposed easily even though I always query a
  single table of the  database?
- Can the .php file be edited to update or delete parts of my database
  or the table in which I query every time?

Please help as I am new to drupal 6 and don't know much about security of php files and drupal nodes.

Comment: If you have an external php file, Drupal will not get involved with it. So you'll need to audit it from a purely PHP perspective

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit (by updating question) to explain what your "search_interface" node is? Do you mean content type?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like any of the questions you have are directly related to Drupal. I highly suggest reading about PHP security concerns. [This is a good resource to get started.](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

That said:

> Is this method secure?

Without looking at specific code, that is hard to say. Since you're running a database query based on user input, it's important you properly sanitize the input before running the query. I suggest using [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of `mysqli_*` functions, since PDO is more widely used now and provides easy ways to use "prepared statements" to protect your database.

> Can some anonymous user access my .php script and get to know my mysql
>   admin password? ( I use admin password during mysqli_connect() )

Not unless the .php script prints the password to the screen. Sounds like it accepts POST data and will return JSON output with data from the database. Make sure your POST data in sanitized before running a query.

> Can my whole database be exposed easily even though I always query a
>   single table of the database?

See above

> Can the .php file be edited to update or delete parts of my database
>   or the table in which I query every time?

Not unless a malicious user has access to your web server